# Golden Exponent? Tetration

Tags: exponentiation, golden-ratio, tetration

I read somebody say “golden exponent $ x^x=x+1 $” now I didn’t understand what he meant but it really fascinated me thinking about some type of tetration version of the golden number. A number with a special or awesome property (not necessarily linked to the golden number). Now that I think about the equation mentioned $ x^x=x+1 $ that does look like an interesting equation for x to satisfy. Anyways, what does everybody think about whether such an analog for tetration exists or not?

Comment: The question is very vague: are you asking for a solution of $x^x=x+1$ or for what analogon of the golden ratio?

Comment: Here are some more digits, using Newton's method: 1.776775040097054697479730744038756748637411 [This Sage script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVj0EKwjAURPc9xSx_rK0GEUUsuPIAPYCQmrQEQ1rSLtLbm7SS4ocQ5s0w_P_QdlJOvKdMqhYdNXoaq_OJ3TKEqVGhVsI8tTJy8djC1TBGpwy_Nr2llfrIiJeX66rb3kFDWzhhO0X8-GtdsjHsXz6BOWqPAvHxhOWKdyBjyTPk4Ow_EIuKGQfIrRx5FYykBxeuJL8PjCWoW4hmpIBwjwdtu8VpnBKfL6hlQxM=&lang=sage) can generate *many* more digits, but if you set the `bits` parameter too high, the SageMathCell server will give up. ;)

Comment: @b00n heT the question was direct my friend. I am asking if the golden number analog exists or not.

Answer (score 4):

Consider that you look for the non trivial zero's of function $$f(x)=x^x-x-1$$
$$f'(x)=x^x (\log (x)+1)-1\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=x^{x-1}+x^x (\log (x)+1)^2$$ The first derivative cancels at $x=1$ and $f(1)=-1$ with $f''(1)=2$. So, we have a minimum and two roots (one of them being the trivial $x=0$.

If you do not want to use a root-finding method, expand $f(x)$ as a series around $x=1$ and obtain
$$f(x)=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-1)^{n+1}$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{12},\frac{3}{40},-\frac{1}{120},\frac{59}{2520
   },-\frac{71}{5040},\frac{131}{10080},-\frac{53}{5040},\frac{179063}{19958400},\cdots\right\}$$

Now, using series reversion, we obtain
$$x=1+\sum_{n=1}^p b_n\,t^n \qquad \text{where}\qquad t=\sqrt{f(x)+1}$$ the first $b_n$ being
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{96},\frac{1}{12},-\frac{7621}{92160},\frac{173}{2880},-
   \frac{243979}{6881280},\frac{901}{60480},\frac{33853717}{118908518400},\cdots\right\}$$

Making $f(x)=0$ that is to say $t=1$, we then have the *estimate*
$$x=\frac{211659504277}{118908518400}\sim 1.78002$$ while the "exact" solution given by Newton method would be $1.77678$.

Comment: Here's a [plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0aiIq9Ct0DXUUdAw0FEw0jPV1AQAV1QGEA==&lang=sage) of $y=x^x-x-1$ for $x\in(0,2.5)$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $0^0=1$ let $x=0$, then $x^x=x+1$ reduces to $0^0=0+1=1$, so $x=0$.

Comment: Sure, $x=0$ is a solution (provided we define $0^0=1$), but it doesn't mean this is the only solution.

Comment: lisyarus the question asked for a value, not all values.